# Python Code to check whether a particular key exists in a dict of lists and dicts

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

For the following definition of a dict:

```
data={
'key_1':1,
'key_2':2,
'key_3':[
    {
        'key_4':[4,5],
        'key_5':[6,7],
        'key_6':8
    },
    {
        'key_4':[9,10],
        'key_5':[11,12],
        'key_6':13
    }
],
'key_7':14
}
```

I basically need to check whether a given key exists in *data* or not and if it does, the values associated with the key must be printed.

**Example:**

input: `key_5`
output: `([6,7],[11,12])`

input: `key_8`
output: `DNE`

**Code that I wrote:**

```
key = input()
def find_key(data,key):
    if key in data:
        print(data[key])
        return

    for k, v in data.items():
            if isinstance(v,list):
                for x in v:
                    if isinstance(x,dict) and find_key(x,key) is not None:
                        print(find_key(x,key))

find_key(data,key)
```

I'm not sure about where to place the condition of 'DNE' in this code. Can I get some help on this?

Comment: You probably want to use recursion to access nested dictionaries here.  There are plenty of questions on SO that discuss how to do this.

Comment: Maybe reconsider how you are building the dict in the first place, so that the values are already lists of lists (or lists of references to lists, to avoid duplication). Single items can be lists of length 1.

Comment: You can use a *try* and *except KeyError* block to handle missing keys

Comment: @eyllanesc: The question you marked as original has the keys at the same depth, this question has nested keys

Comment: @Andomar 

I fixed it, I added the new duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary

Comment: @eyllanesc: Your new suggested original doesn't have arrays in its dictionary. So the accepted answer's `if isinstance(v,dict):` means it won't work for this question, and it's not an exact duplicate either

Comment: @Andomar With the combination of both questions you get the logic of finding the key, if you think it is not duplicated I invite you to reopen it, the community will decide. :D

Comment: @eyllanesc: Why would you vote to close a question if you cannot find an exact duplicate?

Comment: This code may be of help: https://repl.it/@SteamLOLed/ThornyWobblyMicrokernel

Comment: I changed my mind; the other question is not a duplicate - the question of how to search dictionaries recursively needs an appropriate how-to canonical, which is separate from the question of what was wrong with *that particular attempt*.

Answer (score 0):

And what about this? It's a simple recursion...

```
from sys import exit


def check(d, key): # d means dictionary
    for k in d:
        if k == key:
            print(d[key])
        elif (type(d[k]) == list):
            for e in d[k]:
                if (type(e) == dict):
                    check(e, key)
```