# Remove key and its value in nested dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

Looking for a **generic** solution where I can remove the specific key and its value from dict.
For example, if **dict** contains the following nested key-value pair:

```
data={

  "set": {
  "type": "object", #<-- should remove this key:value pair
  "properties": {
    "action": {
      "type": "string",  #<-- should NOT remove this key:value pair
      "description": "My settings"
    },
    "settings": {
      "type": "object", #<-- should remove this key:value pair
      "description": "for settings",
      "properties": {
        "temperature": {
          "type": "object", #<-- should remove this key:value pair
          "description": "temperature in degree C",
          "properties": {
            "heater": {
              "type": "object", #<-- should remove this key:value pair
              "properties": {
                "setpoint": {
                  "type": "number"
                },
              },
              "additionalProperties": false
            },

          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },

      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
}
```

I want an output **dict** without `"type":"object"` across the occurrence of this key:value pair.
The expected output should produce the result without `"type":"object"`

Comment: To remove an element of a dictionary you may have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary)

For your typical problem, you may use recursive functions

Comment: Here's a general purpose recursive dictionary search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a recursive function:

```
def remove_a_key(d, remove_key):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key in list(d.keys()):
            if key == remove_key:
                del d[key]
            else:
                remove_a_key(d[key], remove_key)
```

and call it as:

```
remove_a_key(data, 'type')
```

This recursively removes `'type'` key and it's value from each nested dictionary no matter how deep it is.

Comment: Your logic remove all occurrences of key 'type'. This means the logic removes `type:'object'` which is expected but it also removes `type':'string'` which is not an expected result. Hope I made it clear on the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the logic. Modified to meet my requirement. Please review the modified logic.

```def remove_a_key(d, remove_key, remove_val):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key in list(d.keys()):
            if key == remove_key  and d[key] == remove_val:
                del d[key]
            else:
                remove_a_key(d[key], remove_key,remove_val)
import json
with open('test.json') as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)
path = []
remove_a_key(myjson, 'type','string')```

Comment: @shekarchandra, Your code looks fine. Maybe I read wrong, I answered for the removal of all keys without taking values into consideration. But hope my answer was helpful. Kindly, accept a helpful answer from the two already posted by clicking a tick on the left of the answer (This helps the community identify the helpful solution). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use python module `nested-lookup` to play with any kind of nested documents.
Checkout `https://pypi.org/project/nested-lookup/` for more info.

In your case you need to use method `nested_delete` to delete all occurrences of a key.

**Usage:**

```
from nested_lookup import nested_delete

print(nested_delete(data, 'type'))
```