# Javascript array get path to child

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
{
    "id": "parent",
    "code": "parent",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "rtsp",
            "code": "rtsp",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "001",
                    "code": "cam30",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "002",
                    "code": "cam31",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "003",
                    "code": "cam32",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "004",
                    "code": "cam10",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "005",
                    "code": "cam11",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "006",
                    "code": "cam12",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "007",
                    "code": "cam13",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "008",
                    "code": "cam14",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "009",
                    "code": "cam15",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "010",
                    "code": "cam16",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "011",
                    "code": "cam17",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "012",
                    "code": "cam18",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "013",
                    "code": "cam19",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "014",
                    "code": "cam9",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "015",
                    "code": "cam7",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "016",
                    "code": "cam8",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "017",
                    "code": "cam5",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "018",
                    "code": "cam6",
                    "source": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://192.168.43.29:8554/test"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "test",
            "code": "test",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "cam100",
                    "code": "cam100",
                    "source": "cam100",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "cam100"
                },
                {
                    "id": "zone-a",
                    "code": "zone-a",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "cam100a",
                            "code": "cam100a",
                            "source": "cam100a",
                            "sourceFullScreen": "cam100a"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "cam101",
                    "code": "cam101",
                    "source": "changed",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "changed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cam102",
                    "code": "cam102",
                    "source": "cam102",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "cam102"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cam103",
                    "code": "cam103",
                    "source": "cam102",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "cam102"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cam105",
                    "code": "cam105",
                    "source": "cam105",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "cam105"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "entrepot",
            "code": "entrepot",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "cam1100",
                    "code": "cam1100",
                    "source": "rtsp://125.122.15.12",
                    "sourceFullScreen": "rtsp://125.22.122.11"
                },
                {
                    "id": "safe zone",
                    "code": "safe zone",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "zsd",
            "code": "sdf",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "za",
            "code": "aze",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "qsd",
            "code": "azeqsd",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a function where given a code value it gives me back the full path. is there any arrays package with mæde function for this purpose
I tried the npm array-tools but no success `a.where(json, { "id": idValue })` is giving an empty array, that I was hoping to show recursively.

what I need looks like

`searchPath(array,"003") ==> "003,rtsp,parent"`

Comment: That's not an array

Comment: I do not think that it exists, the structure of objects are by nature very varied. they must be written case by case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers it helped me learning something, however here is my solution that fits perfectly my needs

```
function getCamPath(idValue) {
    console.log("++++++++++++++++" + idValue);
    found_path = "";
    var path = "zone -";
    function search(path, obj, target) {
        var found = false;
        for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
                if (obj[k] === target){
                    value = obj.code 
                    if(value)
                    return path + "-" + value+ "-"
                    else return path;
                }
                 else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
                    value = obj.code
                    var result 
                    if(value)
                    result = search(path + "-" + obj.code + "-", obj[k], target);
                    else result = search(path , obj[k], target);

                     if (result)
                         return result;
                    }
        }
        return false;
    }
    var path = search(path,json,idValue);


    console.log("++++++++++++++++" + path);

    return path;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Very similar task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary). You just should to save all your path and return this path when you find value (key)

Answer (score 1):

1.flatten object
2. get keys
3. find key

```
const flatten = (obj, prefix = '', res = {}) => 
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [key, val]) => {
    const k = `${prefix}${key}`
    if(typeof val === 'object'){ 
      flatten(val, `${k}.`, r)
    } else {
      res[k] = val
    }
    return r
  }, res)

const flattendObj  = flatten(obj);
const found_path  = Object.keys(falttendObj).find(key => key === match)
```