# Access value of dictionary inside list inside dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
MQTT_MSG = {
"waypointMission":
{
    # "plantId": "OLD PLAN",
    "targetWaypoints":
    [
        {
            "latitude": 14.237372,
            "longitude": 77.457814,
            "threatLevel": 1,
            "timestamp": "",
            "waypointExecuted": 0,
            "waypointActions":
            [
                {
                    "action": "pitch",
                    "actionParam": -30
                },
                {
                    "action": "stay",
                    "actionParam": 3000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}
print(MQTT_MSG['waypointMission']['targetWaypoints']['latitude'])
```

I want to change the value of the latitude and longitude of the dictionary.

It is throwing this error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

For this `print(MQTT_MSG['waypointMission']['targetWaypoints'][0])`
It prints a full dictionary inside the targetWaypoints.
I want to print latitude value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to work for this specific case: ```print(MQTT_MSG['waypointMission']['targetWaypoints'][0]['latitude'])```

Comment: @ShimonCohen thank you. It  worked

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to yours but without the added complication of the dict value being a `list`:
[Finding a key recursively in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary)
Here's a modification of the code in [the accepted answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14962509/11547576) to deal with lists:

```
def recursive_search(target, key):
    if key in target:
        return target[key]
    for k, v in target.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            item = recursive_search(v, key)
            if item is not None:
                return item
        elif isinstance(v, list):                #added code to handle the list
            for node in v:
                item = recursive_search(node, key)
                if item is not None:
                    return item
```

Testing this function:

```
recursive_search(MQTT_MSG, "latitude")
>>> 14.237372
```

Note that this will not do so well if there are duplicate keys at the same level (i.e. trying running it with "actionParam", it will only get the first value).