# Python, returning specified key values from a large nested dictionary also containing lists

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

From a nested dictionary also containing lists I would like to return the values for specified keys whether the return value be another dictionary, list or singular value. Example dictionary shown below (OSINT API data of a random IP from Shodan).

From a specified list of keys e.g: `['domains', 'html', 'CN']`

Example required output:

```
'domains': ['facebook.com']
'CN': '*.secure.facebook.com'
'html': ''
```

etc.

The specified keys may appear more than once, or not at all depending on the services on different IP's.

I have code for nested dictionaries but this has stumped me:

```
dataoutput = {'some': 'dictionary'}
filtered_list = ['list of required keys']

def seek_keys(d, key_list):
for k, v in d.items():
    if k in key_list:
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print(k + ": " + list(v.keys())[0])
        else:
            print(k + ": " + str(v))
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        seek_keys(v, key_list)

seek_keys(dataoutput, filtered_list)
```

```
{'region_code': '40', 'ip': 520966673, 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'JP', 'city': 'Tokyo', 'dma_code': None, 'last_update': '2021-08-17T21:19:17.704800', 'latitude': 35.6895, 'tags': [], 'area_code': None, 'country_name': 'Japan', 'hostnames': ['edge-secure-shv-01-nrt1.facebook.com'], 'org': 'Facebook Ireland Ltd', 'data': [{'hash': 960245092, '_shodan': {'id': '35fbfc68-de4a-4433-8d4e-672ed558dc90', 'options': {}, 'ptr': True, 'module': 'http', 'crawler': 'f4bb88763d8ed3a0f3f91439c2c62b77fb9e06f3'}, 'http': {'robots_hash': None, 'redirects': [], 'securitytxt': None, 'title': None, 'sitemap_hash': None, 'robots': None, 'server': None, 'host': '31.13.82.17', 'html': '', 'location': '/', 'html_hash': 0, 'sitemap': None, 'securitytxt_hash': None}, 'os': None, 'opts': {}, 'timestamp': '2021-08-17T21:19:17.704800', 'isp': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'port': 80, 'hostnames': ['edge-secure-shv-01-nrt1.facebook.com'], 'location': {'city': 'Tokyo', 'region_code': '40', 'area_code': None, 'longitude': 139.69171, 'country_code3': None, 'country_name': 'Japan', 'postal_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'country_code': 'JP', 'latitude': 35.6895}, 'ip': 520966673, 'domains': ['facebook.com'], 'org': 'Facebook Ireland Ltd', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nLocation: http://www.facebook.com/\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\r\nX-FB-Debug: uH7oyeyXmCxXRUEDRNZW89jYu4Ncis+tsOcmWtF45ENW8qkGHHJOHpF/WMOclN/XJahPWteD9avoPOcGo4g+Iw==\r\nDate: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 21:19:11 GMT\r\nAlt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n', 'asn': 'AS32934', 'transport': 'tcp', 'ip_str': '31.13.82.17'}, {'hash': 1932904474, '_shodan': {'id': '5e465672-0345-4d13-94b4-f4b5a68e06dd', 'options': {}, 'ptr': True, 'module': 'https', 'crawler': 'bf213bc419cc8491376c12af31e32623c1b6f467'}, 'http': {'robots_hash': None, 'redirects': [], 'securitytxt': None, 'title': None, 'sitemap_hash': None, 'robots': None, 'server': None, 'host': '31.13.82.17', 'html': '', 'location': '/', 'html_hash': 0, 'sitemap': None, 'securitytxt_hash': None}, 'os': None, 'opts': {'vulns': [], 'heartbleed': '2021/08/15 19:43:47 31.13.82.17:443 - SAFE\n'}, 'timestamp': '2021-08-15T19:43:33.722160', 'isp': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'port': 443, 'ssl': {'chain_sha256': ['1e3839fdfad7b0a9098bfe4e2853391a6230357e50c6506e26caecdf85b95c9e', '19400be5b7a31fb733917700789d2f0a2471c0c9d506c0e504c06c16d7cb17c0', '7431e5f4c3c1ce4690774f0b61e05440883ba9a01ed00ba6abd7806ed3b118cf'], 'jarm': '29d29d00029d29d00041d43d00041d92bf66d3b7eed52dd4b99d709662a4a4', 'chain': ['-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nlWlcgHrK154kvhhNjcx59L1iVDM4eCjgk2aDBfVUPBqwP6O+sow=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n', '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\ncPUeybQ=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n', '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n+OkuE6N36B9K\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n'], 'dhparams': None, 'versions': ['-TLSv1', '-SSLv2', '-SSLv3', '-TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'], 'acceptable_cas': [], 'tlsext': [{'id': 65281, 'name': 'renegotiation_info'}, {'id': 11, 'name': 'ec_point_formats'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'session_ticket'}], 'ja3s': 'ccc514751b175866924439bdbb5bba34', 'cert': {'sig_alg': 'sha256WithRSAEncryption', 'issued': '20210627000000Z', 'expires': '20210925235959Z', 'expired': False, 'version': 2, 'extensions': [{'data': '0\\x16\\x80\\x14Qh\\xff\\x90\\xaf\\x02\\x07u<\\xcc\\xd9edb\\xa2\\x12\\xb8Yr;', 'name': 'authorityKeyIdentifier'}, {'data': '\\x04\\x14A\\xdc\\xeaH-\\xcb\\xb2\\xf8J\\xca\\xf4v{C\\r\\x82\\x99\\xc6\\xfbq', 'name': 'subjectKeyIdentifier'}, {'data': '0,\\x82\\x15*.secure.facebook.com\\x82\\x13secure.facebook.com', 'name': 'subjectAltName'}, {'critical': True, 'data': '\\x03\\x02\\x05\\xa0', 'name': 'keyUsage'}, {'data': '0\\x14\\x06\\x08+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x07\\x03\\x01\\x06\\x08+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x07\\x03\\x02', 'name': 'extendedKeyUsage'}, {'data': '0l04\\xa02\\xa00\\x86.http://crl3.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g6.crl04\\xa02\\xa00\\x86.http://crl4.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g6.crl', 'name': 'crlDistributionPoints'}, {'data': "0503\\x06\\x06g\\x81\\x0c\\x01\\x02\\x020)0\\'\\x06\\x08+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x07\\x02\\x01\\x16\\x1bhttp://www.digicert.com/CPS", 'name': 'certificatePolicies'}, {'data': '0u0$\\x06\\x08+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x070\\x01\\x86\\x18http://ocsp.digicert.com0M\\x06\\x08+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x070\\x02\\x86Ahttp://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt', 'name': 'authorityInfoAccess'}, {'critical': True, 'data': '0\\x00', 'name': 'basicConstraints'}, {'data': '\\x04\\x82\\x01i\\x01g\\x00u\\x00\\xf6\\\\\\x94/\\xd1w0"\\x14T\\x18\\x080\\x94V\\x8e\\xe3M\\x13\\x193\\xbf\\xdf\\x0c/ \\x0b\\xccN\\xf1d\\xe3\\x00\\x00\\x01zN\\x94\\x82>\\x00\\x00\\x04\\x03\\x00F0D\\x02 X\\x84h\\xb6\\xc8\\x10F\\xed\\xcc\\xe8x\\\\P\\xc9;\\xbc\\xcf\\x1cO\\x82\\xa5\\x08u\\xc9\\x96im\\xe1\\xc3a\\x10\\xf3\\x02 \\x02\\\'d\\xe4t2h\\xf9`\\xab\\x1d/\\xf6\\xf8\\x14\\x95\\xdfJ\\xf2\\xdf?\\xdc\\x9d\\xbd5\\xfcb\\xc8Z\\x07\\xb1\\xc2\\x00w\\x00\\\\\\xdcC\\x92\\xfe\\xe6\\xabED\\xb1^\\x9a\\xd4V\\xe6\\x107\\xfb\\xd5\\xfaG\\xdc\\xa1s\\x94\\xb2^\\xe6\\xf6\\xc7\\x0e\\xca\\x00\\x00\\x01zN\\x94\\x82P\\x00\\x00\\x04\\x03\\x00H0F\\x02!\\x00\\xd2\\xb52\\x13\\xdb\\x05\\x90=AT\\xee\\xca\\xfc\\xa0H.\\xa3+\\x9f\\x88h\\xfc\\xab\\x9c=EP^\\x1c\\x7f\\xc0^\\x02!\\x00\\xeb\\x16\\x13\\x7f\\x88\\xd3\\xa2\\xd0\\xc4E\\xc8\\x161<X\\x9c\\xff\\x85\\xd5i\\xcd\\x07E(\\x90Z\\xa7\\xfb=|6\\xd1\\x00u\\x00\\xee\\xc0\\x95\\xee\\x8drd\\x0f\\x92\\xe3\\xc3\\xb9\\x1b\\xc7\\x12\\xa3ij\\t{Kj\\x1a\\x148\\xe6G\\xb2\\xcb\\xed\\xc5\\xf9\\x00\\x00\\x01zN\\x94\\x82\\x83\\x00\\x00\\x04\\x03\\x00F0D\\x02 /\\x8a~\\xec\\xea\\xf8cjb\\xd4\\xb9\\x01y\\xa5\\x97\\x8b\\xa7J\\x94tO\\x05\\x11\\x1dX\\x1f\\xf5@v\\xd9$&\\x02 .t\\xdb\\xe3\\xe6\\x15\\xed\\x1c\\xf6\\x1c\\xba@Z]\\xb2\\xa3\\x88\\x8c\\xfb\\x0b\\x12\\xde\\x10\\xc7b)\\xaf{\\t\\xe7\\xe3\\xf9', 'name': 'ct_precert_scts'}], 'fingerprint': {'sha256': '1e3839fdfad7b0a9098bfe4e2853391a6230357e50c6506e26caecdf85b95c9e', 'sha1': '73f915b5c8218ff445be1de566b5c2d0a15d1f6d'}, 'serial': 17057963169357276840551436714988486922, 'subject': {'C': 'US', 'L': 'Menlo Park', 'CN': '*.secure.facebook.com', 'O': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'ST': 'California'}, 'pubkey': {'type': 'rsa', 'bits': 2048}, 'issuer': {'C': 'US', 'OU': 'www.digicert.com', 'O': 'DigiCert Inc', 'CN': 'DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA'}}, 'cipher': {'version': 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 'bits': 128, 'name': 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'}, 'trust': {'revoked': False, 'browser': {'mozilla': True, 'apple': True, 'microsoft': True}}, 'handshake_states': ['before/connect initialization', 'SSLv2/v3 write client hello', 'SSLv2/v3 read server hello', 'SSLv3/TLS read server hello', 'SSLv3/TLS read server certificate', 'SSLv3/TLS read server key exchange', 'SSLv3/TLS read server done', 'SSLv3/TLS write client key exchange', 'SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec', 'SSLv3/TLS write finished', 'SSLv3/TLS flush data', 'SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket', 'SSLv3/TLS read finished', 'SSL negotiation finished successfully'], 'alpn': [], 'ocsp': {}}, 'hostnames': ['edge-secure-shv-01-nrt1.facebook.com'], 'location': {'city': 'Tokyo', 'region_code': '40', 'area_code': None, 'longitude': 139.69171, 'country_code3': None, 'country_name': 'Japan', 'postal_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'country_code': 'JP', 'latitude': 35.6895}, 'ip': 520966673, 'domains': ['facebook.com'], 'org': 'Facebook Ireland Ltd', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nLocation: https://www.facebook.com/\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\r\nX-FB-Debug: ryMLheDS9Y/10RtChKHVKi5BNNNfF4bl3zitEBlNHsseV3TKNfq8YBdEVE64P9DFrlWUOl+KvZm7bi77IoJS6A==\r\nDate: Sun, 15 Aug 2021 19:43:33 GMT\r\nAlt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n', 'asn': 'AS32934', 'transport': 'tcp', 'ip_str': '31.13.82.17'}], 'asn': 'AS32934', 'isp': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'longitude': 139.69171, 'country_code3': None, 'domains': ['facebook.com'], 'ip_str': '31.13.82.17', 'os': None, 'ports': [80, 443]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a key recursively in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: Solution was found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary - thanks