# Find key recursively in dictionary and then list all parent keys

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

My question is similar to [Finding a key recursively in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary) except that once I find the key, I would like to list all parent keys that lead me to the target key.

Logically, I feel like I know what I need to do: store the "path" by appending keys to a list as I descend into the dictionary. If I get to the "bottom" of the dictionary and don't find the key I'm looking for, then I need to reset the path. But, I can't think how do implement this in Python. My current solution just prints out the target key in a list:

```
def list_parents(obj, key):
    path = []
    if key in obj: 
        path.append(key)
        return path

    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            path.extend(list_parents(v, key))

    return path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `path` as an optional parameter:

```
def list_parents(obj, key, path=[]):
    if key in obj:
        path.append(key)
        return path

    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            found = list_parents(v, key, path=path + [k])
            if found:
                return found

    return None


keys = ["A", "E", "G"]
for key in keys:
    res = list_parents({"B": {"A": 2}, "C": 1, "D": {"E": 3, "F": {"G": 3}}, }, key)
    print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['B', 'A']
['D', 'E']
['D', 'F', 'G']
```

Or as an alternative:

```
def list_parents(obj, key):
    if key in obj:
        return [key]

    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            found = list_parents(v, key)
            if found:
                return [k, *found]

    return None
```

To improve the complexity of the above approach you could use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque


def list_parents(obj, key):
    if key in obj:
        return deque([key])

    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            found = list_parents(v, key)
            if found:
                found.appendleft(k)
                return found
    return None
```

The reason to use a deque is that inserting to the front of a list (the line `[k, *found`]) is `O(n)` vs `O(1)` in a `deque`.

Comment: Why does `path` need to be an optional parameter? Because otherwise you overwrite it with an empty list on each recursion?

Comment: That is a trick to keep the state between functions calls, is actually not a best practice. I suggest you use the second alternative

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try this way. It still uses recursion to search through the *nested dict*.

```py
dc  = { 'A' : 'vaa',
        'B' : 'vbb',
        'C' : { 'kc': 'vcc' },
        'D' : { 'kd': { 'kdd1': 'dd1',
                        'kdd11': 'abcc',
                        'key12': 'abcd'},
                    'kdd2': 'dd2'}
                }

def find_parents(D, value):
    for k, v in D.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            parent = find_parents(v, value)  # <--- search down
            if parent:
                return [k] + parent
        elif v == value:
            return [k]

print(find_parents(dc,'abcd')      # ['D', 'kd', 'key12']
```

Answer (score 0):

*Another solution:*

You can make recursive **generator** that yields all paths. In your program you will do a check if the path is "correct" (e.g. the last element in path is your key):

```py
dct = {"a": {"b": {}, "c": {"d": "xxx"}}}


def list_parents(obj, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield (p := path + [k])
            yield from list_parents(v, p)


key = "d"
path = next(path for path in list_parents(dct) if path[-1] == key)
print(".".join(path))
```

Prints:

```py
a.c.d
```