# Strip all occurrences of a particular key from nested list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I am getting an API response as below JSON. I want to retrieve all the values wherever the KEY is "text". But in the same order. How can I achieve this in Python.

```
`{       "version": 1,       "type": "doc",       "content": [         {           "type": "paragraph",           "content": [             {               "type": "text",               "text": "ABC - 1234"             },             {               "type": "hardBreak"             },             {               "type": "text",               "text": "EFG - 648"             }           ]         },         {           "type": "paragraph",           "content": [             {               "type": "text",               "text": "Above EFG is a reissue of 4 payments, that status is at Issued/Requested. "             },             {               "type": "hardBreak"             },             {               "type": "text",               "text": "This payment has not been issued & an payfac file has not been produced. "             },             {               "type": "hardBreak"             },             {               "type": "text",               "text": "Please can you:"             }           ]         },         {           "type": "bulletList",           "content": [             {               "type": "listItem",               "content": [                 {                   "type": "paragraph",                   "content": [                     {                       "type": "text",                       "text": "explain what the status \"Issue/Requesed\" means"                     }                   ]                 }               ]             },             {               "type": "listItem",               "content": [                 {                   "type": "paragraph",                   "content": [                     {                       "type": "text",                       "text": "explain how this status occured"                     }                   ]                 }               ]             },             {               "type": "listItem",               "content": [                 {                   "type": "paragraph",                   "content": [                     {                       "type": "text",                       "text": "would there be any reconcilation issues if I was to change the status to \"Paid/None\" on 1-Jan?"                     }                   ]                 }               ]             }           ]         },         {           "type": "paragraph",           "content": [             {               "type": "text",               "text": "Thank you."             }           ]         }       ]     }`
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: for issue in results["issues"]:
        try:
            all_result['Description'].append(issue["fields"]['description'].[0].[contents].[0].[text]) but this is giving me only first value and I dont know how to pull all the occurences
        except:
            all_result['Description'].append('')

Comment: Have you considered a recursive implementation for parsing the dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

Make a recursive function based upon [Finding a key recursively in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary)

**Code**

```
def recursive_search(data, target):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == target:
                yield value
            else:
                yield from recursive_search(value, target)
                
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            yield from recursive_search(item, target)
```

**Test**

```
# Note: data is the dictionary in the posted question
print(list(recursive_search(data, "text"))
```

**Output**

```
['ABC - 1234', 'EFG - 648', 'Above EFG is a reissue of 4 payments, that status is at Issued/Requested. ', 'This payment has not been issued & an payfac file has not been produced. ', 'Please can you:', 'explain what the status "Issue/Requesed" means', 'explain how this status occured', 'would there be any reconcilation issues if I was to change the status to "Paid/None" on 1-Jan?', 'Thank you.']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to be done by re in python.

First, convert the dictionary to string:

```
s = str(dictionary)
```

This should give the correct solution:

```
re.findall("'text': '(.*?)'", s)
```

since text key must be extracted and may be anywhere in the dictionary, this I believe should be a quick solution.

Comment: This is a dirty solution though. We don't know where this "API response" originated from and what it could possibly contain. If there is some user input involved, someone with malicous intents could get unwanted matches into the system. E.g. `re.findall("'text': '(.*?)'", str({"wrong key": "'text': 'Bobby Tables was here'"}))` is perfectly valid for `re` and returns one match.

Comment: While this may work for the data shown in the question, it's not a sensible approach to this problem. The answer provided by @DarrylG is far superior